# Every 18 or 19 frames from an undistorted .MP4 clip gets pixelized when played via Final Cut

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, conversion, final-cut-pro, final-cut-express, non-square-pixels

I have a .MP4 movie exported from Blender in 24fps in good quality, without any pixelation problems. In whatever movie player I open it, there are no pixelation problems.

When I create a new project in Final Cut, also in 24fps, and I import the clip, and I play it in Final Cut as such, even in the Timeline viewer  (same problem after exporting from Final Cut), then **every 18th or 19th frame gets pixelation problems** as such:

[image: ets]

How to solve please? Should I prepare the Blender movie in another file format?

For your reference, here is an undistorted frame:

[image]

The problem remains if I make a short (1-sec) small-resolution (550x550) sample.

Again, the **19th frame is distorted**:

[image]

It should look more like this:

[image]

Here are my render settings for this small-resolution sample:

[image]

Comment: This looks like "datamoshing", which happens when p, b and i-frames do not align properly. Which export settings did you use? Have you tried rendering a smaller portion again to see if the file is corrupted?

Comment: @FlorianClaaßen I have tried using a short small-resolution new render sample from Blender. The same problem occurs within Final Cut (see my updated answer). What can I do please? My render settings have also been included.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it. In the Video-settings, your Keyframe-intervals are set to 18 frames. For more information about keyframe intervals, this article was quite helpful to me: https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/key-frame-distance-please-help/td-p/8993448?page=1
I believe you should be able to resolve the issue by setting the interval to 1, thus placing a keyframe for each frame.

Comment: @FlorianClaaßen And is there no way to prevent this after importing some clip into Final Cut? Because the original video from Blender took 2 days to render.